# Is there an equivalent of T4MVC for webforms?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, t4mvc

I use T4MVC inside my asp mvc projects, mostly because it's brilliant. Is there an equivalent for asp webforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out David Ebbo (he also did the T4MVC stuff) has given asp webforms a little love as well:
http://blogs.msdn.com/davidebb/archive/2009/07/12/asppathguru-a-little-t4-love-for-asp-net-webforms.aspx

Comment: It's a much smaller scope thing than T4MVC, but I generally the literal string issue is not as big in the WebForms world.

Comment: We still have surprising large amount of literal paths in a project I'm working on. It isn't quite the same scale of problem, but I prefer to keep things as clean as I can.

Answer (score 1):

[PageMethods](http://metasapiens.com/PageMethods/) provide some strongly typed capabilities for WebForms