# T4MVC-like strongly typed link generator to avoid magic strings in Asp.Net Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, t4

I was using T4MVC in my MVC projects to avoid as much magic string as possibile.

I would like to know if there is something similar for ASP.Net Web Forms that generates strongly typed links to the aspx pages and ascx controls.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this previous question: [Is there an equivalent of T4MVC for webforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446679/is-there-an-equivalent-of-t4mvc-for-webforms).

Basically, check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2009/07/12/asppathguru-a-little-t4-love-for-asp-net-webforms.aspx, which I did a few years ago. I haven't tried it in a while, so I can't guarantee it's in good shape, but give it a try!

Comment: Thanks, I already checked out that but I was searching for projects that are actively developed. If there are none, I would like to start one based on your code.

Comment: Sounds good. Let me know once you have something going so I can link to it.